# Sharing playlist between any music player in Windows and Ubuntu

Tags: rhythmbox, music, itunes

Is there a way to share playlists between Windows and Ubuntu? I use iTunes on Windows and Rhythmbox on Ubuntu, but I can switch to any music player on both sides if it will enable sharing of playlists.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your music resides in somehting like a library of mp3 files, shared between the operative systems (either on a common partition in a dual boot system, or via e.g. dropbox) .

In that case, the [.m3u format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U) works with most media players (both iTunes and Rythmbox) on any OS, and you should be able to both create and edit your playlists on either side.

Comment: If you live in a country where it's supported, you could try out [Spotify](http://spotify.com), which is a streaming service that keeps all your playlists etc in the cloud, available at any time on any computer with the client installed.

Comment: Yes, I have a common data partition which contains a folder with all my music. Can you explain exactly how I can use and edit the same playlist on either side?

Comment: As long as you point the two music libraries to the same folder on the shared partition, you shouldn't have to do anything else. If you want to use the built-in libraries and playlist editors, you of course have to configure them to use the m3u files in your library folder, but that should be a no-brainer =)

Comment: Noob alert! Some general pointers would be great. I tried "Save to File" on a playlist, hit m3u format and saved it in the music folder. Is that correct?

Comment: Should be. I have very little experience with either iTunes or Rhythmbox, but that's what I'd try too. Then, when you open the other player, on the other OS, just open that m3u file and start listening =) If it doesn't work, come back here (with details about what happened) and we'll try to help.